# How to retrieve the current number of rows to the end row count in AG Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, ag-grid

In Ag-Grid pagination, it provides the total row count and the row number, for example in the image below you can see `101 to 200 of 8,618`. Where 8618 is the total row count which can be retrieved from `gridApi.paginationGetRowCount()`. But which parameter do I use to get the `101 to 200` count? I am unable to find it in the grid api.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By getting these info:

- total rows ([`paginationGetRowCount`](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-pagination/#reference-pagination-paginationGetRowCount)),
- current page number ([`paginationGetCurrentPage`](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-pagination/#reference-pagination-paginationGetCurrentPage)), and
- page size ([`paginationGetPageSize`](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-pagination/#reference-pagination-paginationGetPageSize))

, you can calculate the first item no. and last item no. for the selected page.

For my use case, I am trying to calculate those values when the page is changed via [`(paginationChanged)`](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-pagination/#reference-pagination-paginationChanged) event.

```
<ag-grid-angular
  ...
  (paginationChanged)="onPaginationChanged($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

For `firstItemNoForCurrentPage`, you need to get the least value between `currentPageIndex * pageSize + 1` and `totalRowCount`. This is aimed at handling when there is no record.

For `lastItemNoForCurrentPage`, you need to get the least value between `currentPageIndex * pageSize + pageSize` and `totalRowCount`. This is aimed at handling when the current page doesn't contain the full number of items as `pageSize`.

```
onPaginationChanged = (event: PaginationChangedEvent<IOlympicData>) => {
  if (!this.gridApi) return;

  // Get current page - 0-index based
  let currentPageIndex = this.gridApi.paginationGetCurrentPage();

  // Get total count
  let totalRowCount = this.gridApi.paginationGetRowCount();

  // Get page size
  let pageSize = this.gridApi.paginationGetPageSize();

  let firstItemNoForCurrentPage = Math.min(
    currentPageIndex * pageSize + 1,
    totalRowCount
  );

  let lastItemNoForCurrentPage = Math.min(
    currentPageIndex * pageSize + pageSize,
    totalRowCount
  );

  console.log('firstItemNoForCurrentPage:', firstItemNoForCurrentPage);
  console.log('lastItemNoForCurrentPage:', lastItemNoForCurrentPage);
};
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vy1cys?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such direct `API`. but you can use two pagination `API` to construct the output data.

```
 1. paginationGetCurrentPage()
 2. paginationGetPageSize()  // you can also put static page size value if it is static
```

you can multiply index value with page-size to get desired output.

> (page-index * page-size + 1) + '--' + ((page-index + 1) * page-size)

```
this.agGrid.api.paginationGetPageSize() *this.agGrid.api.paginationGetCurrentPage() + 1) + '-' +  (this.agGrid.api.paginationGetCurrentPage()+1)*this.agGrid.api.paginationGetPageSize();
```

i have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-avyeqq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) example for you.